# Can I put a job that I have only worked for two weeks on my resume?

Tags: resume

I am currently working for retail and I am NOT liking it at all and this is my first official job besides nannying and tutoring which is like "under the table jobs" they are not with any agencies. And I am in this retail job for two weeks now and I plan on quitting but I am trying to tough it out for the next 4-5 weeks till summer is over.And this is a part-time seasonal position.

Comment: are you asking about putting it on the resume you use to find a better job to replace that one?

Answer (score 5):

Just skip that job.

I don't think you will find many employers who can find a positive aspect in leaving after two weeks. But if somebody does and finally invites you, he'll probably ask you why you did leave after two weeks. You better prepare a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you're able to a) stay there for more than a month; and b)leave because you found a better opportunity, then yes. Put it on your resume until you get about ten years' experience. Then, *stop* listing this one - because it won't be relevant any more, you'll have had other "real" jobs that will hold more weight.

When you do leave, it's best that you either leave because the school year started up and you couldn't balance both work and school; or because you found another job. Leaving this one and having nothing after it, or not having a compelling reason to leave, is not great - especially when you're entering the workforce.

(I've worked short-term/holiday retail. I got other experience fairly fast, stopped listing that job, et voila, stopped listing my short-term retail stuff which was, by then, completely unrelated to what I was doing.)

Good luck!! Working retail can be exasperating, especially if it's just a part-time job - but just keep in the forefront of your mind, "this won't last forever" and keep signing up with other agencies/submitting other resumes in the meantime.